# How to declare list object with M elements

Tags: r

I want to declare a list containing M 3 by 3 matrices.
If I knew the number M in advance, then I can declare such list by:

```
elm <- matrix(NA,3,3)
## Say M = 7
myList <- list(elm,elm,elm,elm,elm,elm,elm)
```

This method becomes cumbersome if M is large. What's worse this method does not work if I do not know the value of M in advance. If I want to declare a vector of length M, I can do it by 
calling:

```
myVec <- rep(NA,M)
```

even if I do not know the value of M in advance. Is there similar way to declare a list of size M?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try

```
mylist <- rep(list(elm),7)
```

which, for S=3, gives

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA
```

By the way, `identical(matrix(NA,3,3),matrix(,3,3))` is true, since matrices are initialized to `NA` by default. See `?matrix`.

Comment: If your matrices are not identical, alexis_laz's answer will be more useful: (1) initialize a list of the correct length and then (2) assign to it with `mylist[[i]]`.

Answer (score 75):

Maybe this:

`myls <- vector("list", length = S)`

Comment: This is good to declare a list of size S. But I want to declare a list containing S 3 by 3 matrix so that, later in my code I can call an (j,k)th element of the i^th 3 by 3 matrix of the list by:   myls[[i]][j,k]

Comment: Try `for(i in 1:length(myls)) { myls[[i]] <- elm } ; myls`