# Evaluating the loop index as a variable name, rather than a string

Tags: r, for-loop, purrr

I would like to evaluate a string, eg `x1`, where `x1 <- "disp"`, as the underlying value, i.e. `disp`, when `x1` is the loop index.

A reproducible example, using the `mtcars` dataset as an example is below:

```r
x1 <- "disp"
x2 <- "hp"

vars <- c("x1", "x2")

for (x in vars){
  print(x)
}
```

Which gives me

```
#> [1] "x1"
#> [1] "x2"
```

## Desired Outcome:

What I'm trying to get is a loop that runs these commands:

```
print(x1)
print(x2)
```

resulting in:

```
#> [1] "disp"
#> [1] "hp"
```

I recognise that the simplest solution would be to bypass `x1` and `x2` completely:

```r
vars <- c("disp", "hp")

for (x in vars){
  print(x)
}
```

But that's less helpful, as it will be very helpful to have `x1`, `x2`, etc, in my (unsimplified) problem.

Also, if `purrr` is a better way to do something like this, instead of a loop, I'd be very interested to understand that better.

If anyone has a suggestion on a better title for the question, I will also be very interested.

## Deeper Question

I simplified my question above, hoping that would be enough to get what I needed, but for context, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
df <- mtcars

x1 <- "disp"
x2 <- "hp"

vars <- c("x1", "x2")

for (x in vars){
  lm(mpg ~ x, data = mtcars)
}
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: you are looking for `get`. do `print(get(x))` in your `for` loop.

Comment: @RonakShah. Wonderful. The question above is a simplication: I'm actually trying to do something more like: `for (x in vars){
  lm(mpg ~ get(x), data = mtcars)
}`. For some reason the `get()` there doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your original question is to use `get`. However, since you want to do something beyond that and want to use `vars` as it is we can use `get` with `as.formula`

```
lst <- vector("list", length(vars))
for (x in seq_along(vars)) { 
   lst[[x]] <- lm(as.formula(paste0("mpg ~", get(vars[x]))), mtcars)
}

#[[1]]

#Call:
#lm(formula = as.formula(paste0("mpg ~", get(vars[.x]))), data = mtcars)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)         disp  
#    29.5999      -0.0412  


#[[2]]

#Call:
#lm(formula = as.formula(paste0("mpg ~", get(vars[.x]))), data = mtcars)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)           hp  
#    30.0989      -0.0682
```

Using `purrr` you can do that with `map`

```
purrr::map(seq_along(vars), ~lm(as.formula(paste0("mpg ~", get(vars[.x]))), mtcars))
```

Comment: And using `%>%`, you could make it more explicit: `vars %>% map_chr(get) %>% paste0("mpg ~ ", .) %>% map(as.formula) %>% map(~ lm(., data=mtcars))`

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you. I'm not familiar with initialising a list this way: `lst <- vector("list", length(vars))`; I've only used `list()` rather than `vector()`. I tried Googling to see if I can find more out about this, but couldn't find a clear explanation. Is there a name or term for what you're doing in that line?

Comment: @RAndStata Whenever you are initialising anything usually it's a good practice to do it with fixed length. So `n <- numeric(10)` is better than only `n <- numeric()`, same goes with lists. There are different ways to initialise a list I showed one way. I had learned it from second answer of this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19340079/how-to-declare-list-object-with-m-elements

Answer (score 1):

Already answered, but:

```
library(rlang)
library(tidyverse)

vars <- exprs(disp, hp) # without "character-quotes"
map(seq_along(vars), ~eval(expr(lm(mpg ~ !!vars[[.x]], mtcars))))

# or
vars <- c("disp", "hp")
map(vars, ~exec("lm", str_c("mpg ~ ", .x), data = mtcars))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply` from `base R` and `reformulate`

```
lapply(mget(vars), function(x) 
       lm(reformulate(response = "mpg", termlabels = x), data = mtcars))
#$x1

#Call:
#lm(formula = reformulate(response = "mpg", termlabels = x), data = mtcars)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)         disp  
#   29.59985     -0.04122  


#$x2

#Call:
#lm(formula = reformulate(response = "mpg", termlabels = x), data = mtcars)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)           hp  
#   30.09886     -0.06823
```